# F is a set of 101 functions from[10] to itself. Prove that $\exists f,g \in F$ and $\exists i,j \in [10]$ such that $f(i) = g(i)$ and $f(j) = g(j)$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, order-theory

> $F$ is a set of $101$ functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,10\}$ to itself.
> Prove that $\exists f,g\in F$ and $\exists i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,10\}=[10]$
> so $f(i)=g(i)$ and $f(j)=g(j)$.

I didn’t manage to solve this problem.
It looks like pigenhole principle but for some reason it didn’t work for me
any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: For each given function $f$ consider pair $(f(1),f(2))\in\{1,2,\ldots,10\}^2$. There are exactly $100$ elements in $\{1,2,\ldots,10\}^2$, so for some functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ this pairs will be the same.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood the idea but how can I write a proof ?

Comment: There is a good answer, I just wanted to point out that the question as written also admits a trivial answer. That is, in your statement there is no requirement that $i \neq j$ and $f \neq g$. So picking either $f = g$ or $i = j$ would be a trivial solution.

Answer (score 3):

When $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, how many distinct functions are there from $\{1,2,...,n\}$ to $\{1,2,...,m\}$?

To define a function $f:\{1,...,n\}\to\{1,...,m\}$ means that for each element $i\in\{1,...,n\}$ we have specified its image $f(i)\in\{1,...,m\}$. Since the codomain has $m$ many elements, there are $m$ choices that we have for $f(i)$. Because there are $n$ many points to specify the image of, we see that there are $m^n$ total functions.

Now we can solve your problem. Take $i=1$ and $j=2$. Then each map $f:\{1,...,10\}\to \{1,...,10\}$ restricts to a map $\tilde{f}:\{1,2\}\to\{1,...,10\}$. From the argument above, we see that there are $10^2=100$ maps $\{1,2\}\to\{1,...,10\}$. Thus, if we have a collection of $101$ maps $f_1,...,f_{101}$ from $\{1,...,10\}$ to itself, then by restricting their common domains we get a collection of $101$ maps $\tilde{f}_1,...,\tilde{f}_{101}$ from $\{1,2\}$ to $\{1,...,10\}$. Since we have shown that there are only $100$ such maps, there must exist $k,l\in\{1,...,101\}$ where $\tilde{f}_k=\tilde{f}_l$. That is, $f_k(1)=f_l(1)$ and $f_k(2)=f_1(2)$ as desired.